# Why do the update/download servers cap out at like 100-130 kb/s?

Tags: downloads

Whenever I'm updating or doing a fresh install it always seems the package servers download speed caps out at 130 kb/s, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Because the servers are always busy, and you may have left it at the default server (and so has everyone else) for your area.  Try changing the server to one closer to you, and you can also let it test the servers to find the one that gives the best response for you - ("Select best server" button)

[image: Software sources on Lubuntu]